# How to re-render Formik values after updated it - React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, formik

I have a screen for update previously data "name, email, age, etc". at the first time I call a function that gets data from server name as `getProfileData()`

after user write the new data I send a POST request for that "update Profile"

and it's a success, but after that, I want to re-render this form with new data, So i call the `getProfileData()` function to get new data but it's not working to re-render Input Values! 
it's just still with previous data

I also try with `componentDidUpdate()` but sadly not re-render :)

So how can i solve it?

Code

```
getProfileData = async () => {
    let USER_TOKEN =
      '....';
    let AuthStr = `Bearer ${USER_TOKEN}`;
    let response = await API.get('/profile', {
      headers: {Authorization: AuthStr},
    });
    let {
      data: {data},
    } = response;
    let password = '';
    let password_confirmation = '';
    let {name, email, avatar, age, gender, country_id} = data;
    let initialValues = [];
    initialValues.push({
      name,
      password,
      password_confirmation,
      email,
      avatar,
      age,
      gender,
      country_id,
    });
    this.setState({initialValues: initialValues, loading: false}, () =>
      reactotron.log(this.state.initialValues[0]),
    );
  };


  updateProfile = async value => {
    let USER_TOKEN =
      '....';
    let AuthStr = `Bearer ${USER_TOKEN}`;
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: AuthStr,
    };
    let response = await API.post('/update_profile', value, {
      headers: headers,
    });
    let {
      data: {data},
    } = response;
    alert(data);
    this.getProfileData(); // called 
  };


 componentDidMount() {
    this.getCountryList();
    this.getProfileData();
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (prevState.initialValues !== this.state.initialValues) {
      console.log('componentDidUpdate', this.state.initialValues);
      this.setState({initialValues: this.state.initialValues});
    }
  }
```

UI

```
<Formik
                  validationSchema={formSchema}
                  initialValues={this.state.initialValues[0]}
                  onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
                    this.updateProfile(values);
                    reactotron.log(values), actions.resetForm();
                  }}>
                  {({
                    handleChange,
                    handleBlur,
                    touched,
                    errors,
                    handleSubmit,
                    values,
                    setFieldValue,
                  }) => (
                    <View>
                      <Item style={styles.item} floatingLabel>
                        <Label style={styles.formLabel}>name</Label>
                        <Input
                          style={styles.value}
                          rounded
                          onChangeText={handleChange('name')}
                          onBlur={handleBlur('name')}
                          value={values.name}
                        />
                      </Item>
                      <Text style={styles.errorText}>
                        {touched.name && errors.name}
                      </Text>
                 </View>
             )}
 </Formik>
```

Answer (score 13):

You can use `enablereinitialize` prop on formik.

```
<Formik 
  enableReinitialize
  ...
/>
```

By default it is false, but if its true, what will happen is if you initialValues change, it will rerender.
So you can store your `initialValues` in state.

for example

```
state = {
  initialValues: { name: '', ...}
}
```

and when you update the profile data just update that state.

```
setState({initialValues: newInitialValues })
```

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean

Comment: `newInitialValues` should be in which function? 

Comment: when your api gets resolved.Probably in your onSubmit after api has been successful.

Comment: @OliverD Updated my answer with a resource link and a slight typo for enableReinitialize

Comment: if i understand you well, in `updateProfile()` but my API does not get any response to except status ;),  resource link not work with me `Your connection is not private
`

Comment: I got your point :))) with `newInitialValues` but sadly i don't know how can i handle it cuz when i get data from API i push it into an array as you see in `getProfileData` and after i setState and use it in Formik I use it by index like this  `initialValues={this.state.initialValues[0]}` So have an idea of how can i push an object of data without using an index? The final result should be something like this `initialValues={this.state.initialValues}`?